# How can I update the figure in Bokeh according to the selected value in Select widget?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to display a figure using Bokeh.plotting. What I want to do is getting the value of select widget and then display the figure of the data related to the selected option.

I have a problem in this line:
`foam_df['test_number']==x_select_test_number.value`

I want to get the selected value in the widget using `update_proj_var_2` function.
Can anyone help me please?

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import Column, row, Spacer, grid, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, Div, Button, Tabs, Panel, Dropdown, ColumnDataSource,MultiSelect, Select, DatePicker, Legend, OpenURL, TapTool, CheckboxButtonGroup, CheckboxGroup, RadioButtonGroup, Plot, Range1d, Text, TextInput, TextAreaInput
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import datetime
import dataiku
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Dropdown


foam_dataset = dataiku.Dataset("foam_data")
foam_df = foam_dataset.get_dataframe()

compo_dataset = dataiku.Dataset("compo_data")
compo_df = compo_dataset.get_dataframe()


source = ColumnDataSource(foam_df)

list_test_number = [str(s) for s in foam_df['test_number'].unique()]
list_product = [str(s) for s in foam_df['product'].unique()]
list_date = [str(s) for s in foam_df['date'].unique()]


welcome_div = Div(text=("<h1>HPC web app</h1>" 
                        "<br><br><br>"))


# Define a title div for experiment filters
project_title_div = Div(text="<h3>experiment filters</h3>")

x_select_test_number = Select(
    title="test_number",  options = sorted(list_test_number)
)

TestDiv = Div()        


def update_proj_var_2(attr, old, new):
    TestDiv.text = "old={},new={},valeurWidget={}".format(old,new,attr)


list_test_number = [str(s) for s in  foam_df['test_number'].unique() if s not in ["None"] ]

x_select_test_number = Select(
    title="test_number",  options = sorted(list_test_number)
)
x_select_test_number.on_change('value',update_proj_var_2)


p = figure(title="Simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
foam_data=foam_df.loc[foam_df['test_number']==x_select_test_number.value,['foam','soil']]
x=foam_data.foam
y=foam_data.soil

p.line(x, y, legend_label="Temp.", line_width=2)

spacer = Spacer(disabled=True, width=10)

intro_layout = row( TestDiv,TestDiv2, spacer,
                       Column(project_title_div,x_select_test_number,
                       row(p)))

intro_tab = Panel(child=intro_layout, title="Welcome")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[intro_tab])

curdoc().add_root(tabs)
curdoc().title = "Test HPC Web Application"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `foam_df['test_number']==x_select_test_number.value` in parentheses like:

```
foam_data=foam_df.loc[(foam_df['test_number']==x_select_test_number.value),['foam','soil']]
```